# About Degree of Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Consider a set $M_{m\times m}(F)$ of matrices of order $m\times n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F_p}$. The set $M_{m\times m}(\mathbb{F_p})$ forms a $Ring$ under the binary operations (addition, multiplication) $\bigoplus_p$ and $\bigotimes_p$ respectively. Also the set $M_{m\times m}(F)$ forms a vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F_p}$.

Suppose, $X$ is a square matrix belongs to the $M_{m\times m}(F)$. Find out the minimal polynomial of $X$ (whose coefficients are from the finite field $\mathbb{F_p}$. Determine the smallest degree of the characteristic polynomial such that the the minimal polynomial of the matrix $X$ would divide the characteristic polynomial of X.

Comment: Never heard of $\bigotimes_2$. Is it matrix multiplication? Also I cannot make any sense of your final sentence.

Comment: You may not heard about many thing in Mathematics, indeed. This is matrix multiplication over modulo p.

Comment: Yeah, but most (all ?) algebraists use the usual notation for that matrix multiplication, and reserve $\otimes$ for something more complicated. Anyway, something is strange about the first paragraph of your question. A matrix is its own additive inverse only, if $p=2$.

Comment: And I agree with Marc. The second paragraph is even stranger. $\lambda^c-I$ is not the characteristic polynomial of $X$. $\det(\lambda I-X)\in F[\lambda]$. Please check the definition and notation from your course material/textbook.

Comment: True Jyrki! A matrix is its own additive inverse only, if p=2. I had in my mind p=2. However the question id edited.

Comment: Better now! But the question is still strange.  The degree of the characteristic polynomial is always $m$. And it is always divisible by the minimal polynomial. So what exactly is the question?